# SQL three tables using only JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, outer-join

I have three tables: **T1** has *id's* from **T2** (*client*) and **T3** (*supplier*), it also acts a **black list**: *T1's* rows with *client's and supplier's id*.

- I want to get the ***supplier's id*** the *client* can buy from.

.

currently **T1** has three rows:

```
T1_id | T2_id | T3_id
   1      1       3 
   2      1       4 
   3      2       3
```

I tried:

```
select T3.id 
from T1 
left join T2 on T2.id = T1.T2_id
right join T3 on T3.id != T1.T3_id 
where T2.id = 1
```

the output is:

```
1
2
3
1
2
4
```

It should be only *1 and 2*. What am I missing? It works fine with *T2.id = 2*.

Comment: I was able to solve it performatically like this:

select T3.id from T3 
where not exists (
select T1.T3_id from T1 
inner join T2
on T2.id = T1.T2_id and T1.T3_id = T3.id
where T2.id = 1
)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this like that

```
select T3.id from T1, T2, T3
where 
T1.T2_id = T2.id and
T3.id <> T1.T3_id and
T2.id = 1
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I think you should consider learning `join` syntax. See [bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

So you have

- List of clients
- List of suppliers
- A map between clients and suppliers.

This should be your table layout.

```
clients
---------
client_id [PK]
client_label

suppliers
---------
supplier_id [PK]
supplier_label

client_suppliers
----------------
client_supplier_id [PK]
client_id 
supplier_id
```

Then you just select which suppliers are mapped to a particular client.

```
SELECT 
    supplier_id
    , supplier_label
FROM 
    suppliers T1 
INNER JOIN 
    client_suppliers T2 ON T2.supplier_id = T1.supplier_id
WHERE 
    T2.client_id = 1
```